# Edit profile information directly from profile screen MVC c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building a Model-View-Controller entity framework website in c#. I have a profile page that displays the user information. I want the user to be able to edit their profile information without having to go to an entirely different page.

For example: On the profile where it says " John's profile ", I want to be able to click a tiny edit name button under the text " John's profile " that turns the label box into a editable text form. I want this to be done from the same page without leaving the profile page.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

**Here is my Markup:**

```
@using testproject.Models;
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;


@{
    dynamic student; 
    string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var query = from st in context.Profiles
                    where st.UserId == userID
                    select st;
         student = query.FirstOrDefault<Profile>();
    }
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Profile Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>    
</div>   
<div class="row">
    <h1> @student.FirstMidName @student.LastName 's Profile</h1>
</div>
```

**Here is my Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace testproject.Models
{
    public class Profile
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**Here is my Controller:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using testproject.Models;

namespace testproject.Controllers
{
    public class PageController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Page
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Profile profile = new Profile();

            string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();



            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var query = from st in context.Profiles
                            where st.UserId == userID
                            select st;

                var student = query.FirstOrDefault<Profile>();

                var name = student.FirstMidName;

            }



            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I am only able to edit the profile from the auto generated scaffolding that visual studio generated for my profile view.

Comment: Why no JavaScript?. JS is about the only way to do it without going to a new page.

Comment: I went ahead and edited my question to include JavaScript solutions. I did not mean to make it sound like I was against them.